# Can orbeon serve static html from database?

Tags: orbeon

I need to populate a static text field value with html code obtained from database service.

I set the flag to use HTML tags, and it correctly work with the static text wrote in the module source, but when my action set a new value html tags are escaped and not echoed as html when i run the module.

I've tried to escape with < > and using all my text on database in `<![CDATA[]]>` nothing helps.

Comment: It's a bit hard to tell without a running form. Can you share that?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get this using an HTML field (tinymce) with read-only set to true().

these the relevant parts of oxf:

field definition:

```
<xh:tr>
    <xh:td>
        <fr:tinymce xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
            xmlns:xxbl="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/xbl"
            xmlns:f="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/formatting"
            id="requisiti_html-control"
            bind="requisiti_html-bind">
            <xf:label ref="$form-resources/requisiti_html/label"/>
            <xf:hint ref="$form-resources/requisiti_html/hint"/>
            <xf:alert ref="$fr-resources/detail/labels/alert"/>


        </fr:tinymce>


    </xh:td>
</xh:tr>
```

binding:

```
<xf:bind id="requisiti_html-bind" ref="requisiti_html" name="requisiti_html"
    relevant="$requisiti_visibile eq 'Y'"
    readonly="true()"/>
```

the db query:

action to populate field:

```
<xf:instance id="recupera_tendine_pbs_mod_011-instance" class="fr-database-service"
    xxf:exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
    <body xmlns:secure="java:org.orbeon.oxf.util.SecureUtils"
        xmlns:frf="java:org.orbeon.oxf.fr.FormRunner"
        xmlns:version="java:org.orbeon.oxf.common.Version"
        xmlns:fbf="java:org.orbeon.oxf.fb.FormBuilder">&lt;sql:config xmlns:sql="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/sql"&gt;
        &lt;sql:datasource&gt;mysql&lt;/sql:datasource&gt;
        &lt;sql:query&gt;SELECT a_key, a_value FROM pbs_mod_011
        WHERE idComune = &lt;sql:param type="xs:decimal" select=""/&gt; ORDER BY a_value ASC&lt;/sql:query&gt;

        &lt;/sql:config&gt;</body>
</xf:instance>
<xf:submission id="recupera_tendine_pbs_mod_011-submission" class="fr-database-service"
    ref="instance('fr-service-request-instance')"
    resource="/fr/service/custom/orbeon/database"
    method="post"
    serialization="application/xml"
    replace="instance"
    instance="fr-service-response-instance"/>

<xf:action ev:event="xforms-submit-done"
    ev:observer="recupera_tendine_pbs_mod_011-submission"
    context="instance('fr-service-response-instance')">

    <xf:action class="fr-set-control-value-action">
        <xf:var name="control-name" value="'requisiti_html'"/>
        <xf:var name="control-value" value="/response/row[a-key=&#34;requisiti_html&#34;]/a-value"/>
    </xf:action>
</xf:action>
```